# Remove underscore and pick first value seperately and next two values in another cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Kindly suggest on how remove underscore and pick first value seperately and next two values together in another cell in excel

Example

```
|List Item | Desired Value1 | Desired Value 2|
|----------|----------------|----------------|
|Add_Token | Add            | Token          |
|Add_Project_Part| Add      | Project Part   |
```

I have tried

```
=RIGHT(A1,FIND("_",A1))
```

This is capturing only right most value but not middle valude together.
also

```
=LEFT(B2,FIND("_",B2)-1)
```

This is capturing left value "Add".

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("_",A1)-1)
```

Formula in `C1`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("_",A2)+1,LEN(A2)),"_"," ")
```

Comment: Thanks JvdV however I don't need "_" value in the C column value.  Can you suggest?

Comment: With `MS365` --> `=LET(x,A1:A2,
HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(x,"_",1),SUBSTITUTE(TEXTAFTER(x,"_",1),"_"," ")))`